# Request HTTP rest resource with custom headers and authorization?

Tags: java, android, python, http, google-app-engine

I'm working on a web service and I need a code for making an HTTP request in java using basic authentication. I found lots of code at the internet but no one worked as expected.
Does anyone knows some library and/or link to do this?

Here is a python equivalent to what I want...

```
import urllib2
import base64

req = urllib2.Request('http://testeserjaum.appspot.com/rest/metadata')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)')
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' %('user', 'pass'))
print base64string
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" %base64string)
lol = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print lol.read()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, you just use the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class. The Android team has actually put a lot of development time into making this class extremely performant and usefully. I highly recommend it!

P.S. If you're really curious, checkout this [blog post from the android dev team](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Apache HTTP Client (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).  It makes HTTP communication pretty simple.

Comment: The android dev team actually recommends you don't use this class for new apps. They don't do active development on it any more because it's so old and there's a bunch of backwards compatibility stuff that prevents them from making it run well. For details, checkout this blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html